# Why am I receiving a segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c, function, pointers, segmentation-fault

This program is supposed to function as a complex number calculator. I am required to use these functions with the given parameters. When I run the program, I am able to input 4 numbers after I choose the operation. Right after I press enter on the fourth number, I receive an error called "segmentation fault: 11". I cannot find out why I am getting this message.

I have included the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void read_num(float *real_part, float *imaginary_part) {
    float realnumberholder, imagnumberholder;
    printf("Please type in the real component: ");
    scanf("%f", &realnumberholder);
    *real_part = realnumberholder;
    printf("Please type in the imaginary component: ");
    scanf("%f", &imagnumberholder);
    *imaginary_part = imagnumberholder;
}

void read_nums(float *real_part_1, float *imaginary_part_1,
               float *real_part_2, float *imaginary_part_2)   {
    printf("Reading the first imaginary number...");
    read_num(real_part_1, imaginary_part_1);
    printf("Reading the second imaginary number...");
    read_num(real_part_2, imaginary_part_2);
}

void print_complex(float real_part, float imaginary_part) {
    printf("The operation yields %6.3f + %6.3fi", real_part,
           imaginary_part);
}

void add(float real_part_1, float imaginary_part_1, float
         real_part_2, float imaginary_part_2, float *real_result, float
         *imaginary_result) {
    read_nums(&real_part_1, &imaginary_part_1, &real_part_2,
              &imaginary_part_2);
    *real_result = (real_part_1 + real_part_2);
    *imaginary_result = (imaginary_part_1 + imaginary_part_2);
    print_complex(*real_result, *imaginary_result);
}

void subtract(float real_part_1, float imaginary_part_1, float
              real_part_2, float imaginary_part_2, float *real_result, float
              *imaginary_result) {
    read_nums(&real_part_1, &imaginary_part_1, &real_part_2,
              &imaginary_part_2);
    *real_result = (real_part_1 - real_part_2);
    *imaginary_result = (imaginary_part_1 - imaginary_part_2);
    print_complex(*real_result, *imaginary_result);
}

void multiply(float real_part_1, float imaginary_part_1, float
              real_part_2, float imaginary_part_2, float *real_result, float
              *imaginary_result) {
    read_nums(&real_part_1, &imaginary_part_1, &real_part_2,
              &imaginary_part_2);
    *real_result = (real_part_1 * real_part_2);
    *imaginary_result = (imaginary_part_1 * imaginary_part_2);
    print_complex(*real_result, *imaginary_result);
}

int main()
{
    int option;
    float realone = 0;
    float imaginaryone = 0;
    float realtwo = 0;
    float imaginarytwo = 0;
    float *realresult;
    float *imaginaryresult;


    printf("\nComplex Number Arithmetic Program.\n");
    printf("1) Add two complex numbers\n2) Subtract two complex
           numbers\n3) Multiply two complex number\n4) Quit\nChoose an
           option (1-4): ");
    scanf("%d", &option);

    while(option != 4) {

        switch(option) {
        case 1 :
            add(realone, imaginaryone, realtwo,
                imaginarytwo, realresult, imaginaryresult);
            printf("1) Add two complex numbers\n2)
                   Subtract two complex numbers\n3) Multiply
                   two complex number\n4) Quit\nChoose an
                   option (1-4): ");
            scanf("%d", &option);
            break;
        case 2 :
            subtract(realone, imaginaryone, realtwo,
                     imaginarytwo, realresult, imaginaryresult);
            printf("1) Add two complex numbers\n2)
                   Subtract two complex numbers\n3) Multiply
                   two complex number\n4) Quit\nChoose an
                   option (1-4): ");
            scanf("%d", &option);
            break;
        case 3 :
            multiply(realone, imaginaryone, realtwo,
                     imaginarytwo, realresult, imaginaryresult);
            printf("1) Add two complex numbers\n2)
                   Subtract two complex numbers\n3) Multiply
                   two complex number\n4) Quit\nChoose an
                   option (1-4): ");
            scanf("%d", &option);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Please input a valid menu
                   option\n");
            printf("1) Add two complex numbers\n2)
                   Subtract two complex numbers\n3) Multiply
                   two complex number\n4) Quit\nChoose an
                   option (1-4): ");
            scanf("%d", &option);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (option == 4) {
        printf("Bye!\n");
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: `imaginaryresult` never points to any determinate memory. You left it unintialized. Frankly, it shouldn't be a pointer it `main`. it should be a regular `float` and you should pass it's *address* to your functions. LIkewise for `realresult`.

Comment: As @WhozCraig wrote, even if these parameters are semantically "out" parameters, they still need storage space to be allocated somewhere. And your functions don't dynamically allocate memory for the results (which is a good thing, since each `malloc` then requires a `free` at some point). So if you want to pass a pointer to get the result, you will need to have a `float x` somewhere and then pass its address using `&x`.

Comment: I don't know the rules you have to make your program, but maybe you'd like to use a structure `struct complex { float r; float i };`

Comment: This program doesn't need any pointers. Why are you using them? Is it an assignment to write a calculator using pointers?

Comment: You really need to fix the coding style and indention. This code isn't readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
float *realresult;
float *imaginaryresult;
```

To this:

```
float realresult;
float imaginaryresult;
```

Then change the function invocations to take the address instead:

```
add(realone, imaginaryone, realtwo,
            imaginarytwo, &realresult, &imaginaryresult);
```

(note the `&` symbols)

And it will work. As it was previosuly, without those memory allocations, those two pointers aren't pointing to any valid memory. They are uninitialized, and accessing them like you did is undefined behavior. What usually happens in practice is that it tries to interpret a rubbish value as an address and tries to access that address, which leads to the segmentation fault.

Comment: Please not this `malloc` cargo culting - they can be very well be `float`s in `main` as pointed out in a comment to the question.

Comment: `float *realresult = malloc(sizeof(float));` is really pointless, I'd remove that from the answer. `float realresult;` and using the `&realresult` later is good enough.

Comment: Good call. There really is no merit in even having the `malloc` version around.

Answer (score 4):

The realresult and imaginaryresult are taken as pointers in the main function. They should be just float variables and you should pass the address of these variables to the respective functions. Change the following lines

```
float *realresult;
float *imaginaryresult;
```

to

```
float realresult;
float imaginaryresult;
```

Also, the function calls need to be modified to

```
add(realone, imaginaryone, realtwo, imaginarytwo, &realresult, &imaginaryresult);
...
subtract(realone, imaginaryone, realtwo, imaginarytwo, &realresult, &imaginaryresult);
....
multiply(realone, imaginaryone, realtwo, imaginarytwo, &realresult, &imaginaryresult);
```